# Both Parallel and Perpendicular Lines Using Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, slope

I recently came across the idea that two lines that are both parallel and perpendicular, exist in the complex plane. Obviously, I know this is probably silly, but I am interested to see what the flaw is in the equations below.

y = ix + 3

y = (-1/i)x + 2

When both slopes are multiplied by i/i, the slope of the first line remains the same at i but the second equation:

-1/i * i/i = -i/i^2

= -i/-1

= i

New slope: y = ix + 2

So this is proof that the lines are perpendicular and parallel. However, I know this is very flawed in some way, I believe it is something to do with a/a is always 1. I am interested to hear your thoughts...

Comment: Those are not lines in the complex plane.

Comment: Interesting.  Both have "slope" $i$, so these two "complex lines" in $\mathbb C^2 = \mathbb R^4$ are parallel.  But of course in the $4$ dimensional space $\mathbb C^2$ the usual criterion for "perpendicular" is not working.

Comment: If you are talking about the usual complex plane with $z=x+iy$, then $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, and these equations have no solutions.

Comment: @GEdgar In $\mathbb{C}^2$, don't the lines intersect in $(x,y)=(1+i,2+i)$?

Comment: For two complex lines $y = m_1x + b_1, y = m_2x+b_2$ the criterion for "perpendicular" should be $-1/m_1 = \overline{m_2}$.

Comment: @saulspatz ... the point $(x,y)=(1+i,2+i)$ is not on the second line $y=ix+2$.

Comment: @GEdgar Wasn't the line $y=i+2$ until a moment ago?

Comment: It was, but that was an error, judging by the "parallel" and "perpendicular" claims in the OP.

Comment: Understand that if $x, y$ are complex numbers, then since $\Bbb C$ is two dimensional, so as plop says, these are not the equations of lines but of planes in the four dimensional space $\Bbb C^2$. This is why a change to normal 2-dimensional test for perpendicularity is needed.